# Matching an exact number of tokens in a regex

Tags: regex

I never worked deep with regex...

I have this regex: `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-<environment>-<org>-<area>-<title>`

The first 3 words including the dashes are always the same, the rest, varies only in that the environment particle could or could not be there.

Now, I need to set the regex variable to `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-<env>-<org>-<area>-<title>` if the environment is there, or else set the regex variable to `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-<org>-<area>-<title>` if is not.

In other words, I need 4 word-dash token (`UAT-<org>-<area>-<title>`) in the first case, and 3 (`<org>-<area>-<title>`) in the other.

I have this regex in the first case: `LAX\-Application\-CustomerDrives\-([A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\-[A-Za-z]+)` which works for when there are 4 pairs (when environment is there) and doesn't match if there are only 3, but the regex: `LAX\-Application\-CustomerDrives\-([A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\-[A-Za-z]+)` will match in any case.

I need to explicitly match for 4 and only 4 pairs (`/[A-Z]\-/g`), if the environment variable is set, and 3 and only 3 pairs if is not set.

I've tried with `LAX\-Application\-CustomerDrives\-([A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\-[A-Za-z]+){3}` and `{4}` but it won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and their desired outputs as well? Try to make the input types as varied as possible while withing the bounds of the question.

Comment: If I get `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-AMD-LSC-Analyst` and the ENV variable is there, it should not match anything of the sort; if I get the same string but then ENV is  not there, it should match always. If I get `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-UAT-AMD-LSC-Analyst` and the ENV is there, it should match for 4 tokens, never for 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the 3 or 4 tokens without the leading hyphen, you could match the hyphen after the 3 words which are always there.

Then capture a sequence of 3 or for follwing words in a capturing group.

```
\bLAX-Application-CustomerDrives-([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+){2,3})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent the word being part of a larger word
- `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-` Match literally with the ending `-`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ char a-zA-Z
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z]+){2,3}` Repeat 2 or 3 times matching a `-` and 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/InSDEq/1)

---

**Edit**

If you want 2 patterns for either 3 or 4 occurrences, you could use `(?!\S)` to assert not a non whitspace char on the right.

For 3 occurrences:

```
\bLAX-Application-CustomerDrives-([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+){2})(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ihrzhY/1)

For 4 occurrences:

```
\bLAX-Application-CustomerDrives-([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+){3})(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccf5pq/1)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with these input:
-`LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-UAT-KLM-CPS-Analyst
LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-BNK-CPS-Caller` and for both it matches, which is good but I need two of them: one for the first input that completely excludes the second input, and one for the second input that completely excludes the first input.

Comment: @user2044806 I have updated the answer with 2 additional patterns, one for 3 and one for 4 occurrences.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. You know of a particular course on regexs?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

`LAX-Application-CustomerDrives(-[A-Z]+){3,4}`

Because what you actually need is to match 4 tokens when there are 4 and 3 tokens when there are 3. `<env>`, that decides between 3 and 4, is actually the extra token. Conclusion : match at least 3 values, and up to 4.

This type of bounds is greedy : it will always try to read the token 4 times if possible.

Example (JS) : `'LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-A-B-C-D'.match(/LAX-Application-CustomerDrives(-[A-Z]+){3,4}/)` matches

Note that escaping hyphens is not mandatory expect in char sets ([a-z-] for example).

**Update**
Now I better understand your need. What you need then is a negative lookahead.

`LAX-Application-CustomerDrives(-[A-Z]+){4}` matches 4 tokens

`LAX-Application-CustomerDrives(-[A-Z]+){3}(?!-[A-Z]+)` matches 3 tokens and fails when 4.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I need two regex: the first will match `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-ENV-A1-A2-A3`, meaning matching only and only if the last 4 tokens are there, and at the same time if there are 3, it will not match. The second regex will match only when `LAX-Application-CustomerDrives-A1-A2-A3` comes, this is, when 3 and only 3 tokens come; if 4 are showing up, it will not match.

Comment: @user2044806: ok got it. You need a negative lookahead.I updated my answer accordingly.